# SQL query too long, is there a way to clean the codes?

Tags: sql, join, long-integer

i am still new to sql and my code takes too long to run.

this is my code

```
SELECT SUM(b.matchusertime)
FROM(
SELECT fulldate, realmatchid, isclanmatch
FROM go_int.int_match
WHERE (fulldate BETWEEN '2013-06-30' AND '2013-07-27') AND isclanmatch = 0
GROUP BY realmatchid)a
INNER JOIN go_int.int_match_user b
ON b.realmatchid = a.realmatchid
WHERE (b.fulldate BETWEEN '2013-06-30' AND '2013-07-27')
```

what i am trying to do, is to take the userids from the match table which are not in a clan match and match it onto match_user table to find out the total duration of non-clan matches.

but each time i run the query, it takes like 45minutes or more and doesnt return me result due to time out issues and etc.

Comment: How large are the tables?  What database are you using?  What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: the tables are huge like >500,000 rows. 

match has probably a number of columns, about 8. and for match user it has about 15 columns.

Comment: Without knowing what your current indexes are and the database you are using and the query plan for your query, any hints on performance are just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(b.matchusertime)
FROM(
SELECT fulldate, realmatchid, isclanmatch
FROM go_int.int_match INNER JOIN go_int.int_match_user b 
ON b.realmatchid = a.realmatchid 
WHERE (fulldate BETWEEN '2013-06-30' AND '2013-07-27') AND isclanmatch = 0
GROUP BY realmatchid)a
```

I modified your same query.Just give a try using this one. If you can paste your sample table structure with dummy data, It may help us to give a support.  Thanks.

Comment: hi, it returned an error (1052). stating fulldate is ambiguous

Comment: in the where condition mention fulldate and isclanmatch  is from which table. for ex : - yourTable.fulldate and yourTable.isclanmatch

Comment: yea i did that. but it gave an error.


`SELECT SUM(b.matchusertime)
FROM(
SELECT fulldate, realmatchid, isclanmatch
FROM go_int.int_match a INNER JOIN go_int.int_match_user b 
ON b.realmatchid = a.realmatchid 
WHERE (b.fulldate BETWEEN '2013-06-30' AND '2013-07-27') AND b.isclanmatch = 0
GROUP BY realmatchid)a`

Comment: what is the error? fix this thing also :- group by yourTable.realmatchid

Comment: `Error Code: 1052
Column 'fulldate' in field list is ambiguous`

yea i have done that too.

Comment: it feels like there isnt a declaration of match?

Comment: you have to call every column using table name.
(SELECT fulldate, realmatchid, isclanmatch -----< fix that

your error is about that the sql can not understand which fulldate you ask.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery gets run for every row in the join table. A workaround for this is to nest the subquery inside another select statement. This will cause a derived table (temporary table stored in memory) to be created from the subquery and eliminate the need for it to be run for every row.

```
SELECT SUM(b.matchusertime)
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT fulldate, realmatchid, isclanmatch 
    FROM go_int.int_match
    WHERE (fulldate BETWEEN '2013-06-30' AND '2013-07-27') AND isclanmatch = 0
    GROUP BY realmatchid
  ) dt
) a
INNER JOIN go_int.int_match_user b ON b.realmatchid = a.realmatchid
WHERE b.fulldate BETWEEN '2013-06-30' AND '2013-07-27';
```

Comment: Actually, scratch that. That's only the case for dependent subqueries.

Comment: It'll work as is. After taking a closer look at the query though I don't think that was the problem. Can you post a couple of sample rows for each table along with an example of the expected result? Perhaps with a better understanding we can come up with a more efficient query.